# API method to get the list of Microsoft owned APIs and Permissions

Tags: c#, visual-studio, api, azure-active-directory, endpoint

[Sample screenshot from portal.azure.com](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UmEVK.jpg)

Is there any way to get the list of Microsoft-owned API through an API method/Endpoint which can provide all the APIs owned by Microsoft with there corresponding permissions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Microsoft has created a number of applications, many of which expose some number of APIs. Each of these applications have a different application identity, and their APIs are accessible through different endpoints.

There does not exist a meta-service which lists all of the application identities and API endpoints for all Microsoft services.

However, there is the [Microsoft Graph](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph), which may solve your issue. The Microsoft Graph is a single API which gives you access to a number of other Microsoft APIs like Azure AD, SharePoint, Outlook, etc... By getting a token to the Microsoft Graph, you can access all of these different endpoints without needing to do additional token exchanges or multiple consent prompts. All the permissions for the Microsoft Graph are listed [here](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/permissions_reference), and are accessible via API.

If you are looking to explicitly duplicate what the Azure Portal is doing when listing Microsoft services, you should know that they use a white-list of services to determine what shows up on their "Select an API" experience. That list could change at any time, and is not centralized or programmatically generated. You can find a list of common Microsoft Applications and their App IDs and Resource URLs on a blog post I wrote: [Common Microsoft Resources in Azure Active Directory](http://shawntabrizi.com/aad/common-microsoft-resources-azure-active-directory/)